# selecting from same table with multiple sessions

Tags: oracle, select, locking, rownum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force Oracle to return TOP N rows with SKIP LOCKED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117254/force-oracle-to-return-top-n-rows-with-skip-locked)

I am experiencing some problems with FOR UPDATE clause on Oracle. What I want to do is select a number of values (say 1000, but this value might be changed by the user at runtime) from a table and process them. But, my application may run on multiple nodes and all of them will use the same table, so I have to lock the records to prevent same records to be fetched by multiple nodes.

To demonstrate it, lets create a sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE t (ID PRIMARY KEY) AS SELECT ROWNUM FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000;
```

This is how I select the records. Here I tried to fetch 3 records.

```
SELECT rownum r, a.ID i
  FROM (SELECT * FROM t ) a 
 WHERE  rownum <= 3
 FOR UPDATE skip locked
```

This query returns 3 records

```
+---+---+
+ R + I +
+---+---+
+ 1 + 1 +
+---+---+
+ 2 + 2 +
+---+---+
+ 3 + 3 +
+---+---+
```

When I ran the same query from another session (without commiting the session 1), I get an empty resultset. But what I really want is fetch the next 3 items (4, 5, 6 in this case). I understand that this is the expected behaviour, but cannot find an appropriate solution to it. How can I solve this without creation an Oracle procedure?

Comment: I would use BULK COLLECT and LIMIT see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770317/sql-for-update-skip-locked-query-and-java-multi-threading-how-to-fix-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This came up before, and I gave a fairly detailed answer then:

[Force Oracle to return TOP N rows with SKIP LOCKED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117254/force-oracle-to-return-top-n-rows-with-skip-locked/6649586#6649586)

I cannot really think of another way (short of using a queue) than the information that is given in the thread above.

Comment: I found your answer very useful and tried a quick example. It seems to be working properly. I will try it with spring framework also. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Instead of the `SKIP LOCKED` in your example, what you're actually asking for is `READ UNCOMMITTED`, or a 'dirty read' which Oracle's not keen on.

I'd have a read of this question/answer: [Does oracle allow the uncommitted read option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208236/does-oracle-allow-the-uncommited-read-option)

Comment: No, I don't want to read dirty data. What I want to do is to read the next 3 items (4, 5, 6). May be it would be better if I edit the question to state that.

Comment: OK, so would moving the `skip locked` inside your subquery work? As in: `(SELECT * FROM t FOR UPDATE skip locked) a`

Comment: Isn't that will lock the whole table? Besides when I do that, I got an error saying "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"

Comment: I forgot to add the SQL:  SELECT rownum r, a.ID i
   FROM (SELECT *
           FROM t FOR UPDATE skip locked ) a 
  WHERE  rownum <= 3

Comment: I'm not able to test this myself right now - I'll let someone else jump in and help hopefully.